# How to have selected class in update page in vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

In `Vuejs 2.0` I've a following set of data:

```
const tags = {
   Investor:[
     {display:"Mutual Fund", value:"Investor - Mutual Funds"},
     {display:"Insurance", value:"Investor - Insurance"},
     {display:"FII", value:"Investor - FII"},
   ],
   Research:[
     {display:"Research - Tier I", value:"Research - Tier I"},
     {display:"Research - Tier II", value:"Research - Tier II"},
  ] 
}
```

I'm having following set of buttons which shows these tags:

```
<div class="col-sm-4 border-right">
    <div>
        <button v-for="(obj, key) in tags"
                :key="key"
                @click.prevent="currentTag = key"
                class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">
            {{key}}
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div>
        <button v-for="tag in tags[currentTag]"
                :key="tag"
                class="btn btn-xs"
                :class="tagClass(tag)"
                @click.prevent="selectedTag = tag">
            {{tag.display}}
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

To get the selected tags I'm having a variable named:

```
currentTag: '',
selectedTag: '',
```

Now i'm having `tagClass(tag)` to toggle the class:

```
tagClass(tag){
    return {
        'btn-warning': this.selectedTag === tag,
        'btn-primary': !(this.selectedTag === tag)
    }
},
```

Now while getting the update page I'm putting values in `current tag` and `selectedTag` like this:

```
this.currentTag = response.data.contact.parentTag
this.selectedTag = response.data.contact.selectedTag
```

Now I'm able to view the child tags selected from the parent but I'm unable to have selected class in it. I want the data which is being set to `seletedTag` should have class `btn-warning`
In backend `PHP` I'm calculating and passing the value as

```
$selectedTag['value'] = $contact->tag;
$tags = explode('-', $contact->tag);
$contact->parentTag = $tags[0];
$selectedTag['display'] = $tags[1];
$contact->selectedTag = $selectedTag;
```

Comment: Can you show an example of `response.data` and also the method you are using that contains `this.currentTag = response.data.contact.parentTag`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that the `tagClass` method is checking to see if the `tag` is equal to the `selectedTag`. Since `tag` and `selectedTag` are objects, when you set it manually, `selectedTag` is *never* going to be equal to any of your tags. Instead, look for the `tag` that you have locally that matches the `tag` that you received from the server.

Wherever you are doing this

```
this.currentTag = response.data.contact.parentTag
this.selectedTag = response.data.contact.selectedTag
```

Change it to this

```
this.currentTag = response.data.contact.parentTag
const selectedTag = response.data.contact.selectedTag
this.selectedTag =  this.tags[this.currentTag].find(t => t.value === selectedTag.value)
```

[Example](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/WjPqMg?editors=1010).

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, do you want me to place it in `mounted()` as you have done in example, and I'm already defining `selectedTag` in `data()` then why again defining with const.

Comment: @NitishKumar You can likely do it wherever you are right now. I just did it there for convenience.

Comment: Still not resolved, I'm passing `selectedTag` in array format in back-end I've updated the question please review.

Comment: @NitishKumar I don't do anything with php. Can you show us how the JSON comes down client side?

Comment: That is the problem, I'm having data in array format not in json format. Let me check by changing the format to json

Comment: What is the array? [value, display]?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145049/discussion-between-nitish-kumar-and-bert-evans).